# How to write to JSON file using jq without changing binary file at Powershell?

Tags: json, powershell, jenkins, jq

I have a simple `jq` command & it works when I run it in Powershell at a local computer. The binary file does not change.

```
jq 'query.....' $srcJson > $destinationJson
```

When Jenkins run the command above (located in a Powershell file) at a separate Windows computer, the `$destinationJson` binary file has changed.

For example:

[image]

`bad-swagger.json` file is created in Jenkins.

`swagger.json` file is created in local PowerShell windows.

Both text files have the same content but the file size is different by twice & the `giff diff` reveals that the binary file is different.

How to write in-place or save the new jq output to a json file without changing its binary file using Powershell?

Thank you.

Comment: You keep saying "binary file", but your source file is necessarily text (JSON), and the output from `jq` is also text - so what exactly is it you refer to as a "binary file"?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I have added a diagram in my original post above

Comment: `>` in Windows PowerShell defaults to UTF16LE encoding, give `jq 'query...' $srcJson |Out-File $destinationJson -Encoding UTF8` a try

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, your solution works. If you could copy your comment as a solution below, I would mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in output you're seeing is likely due to the fact that the file output redirection operation (`>`) in Windows PowerShell defaults to UTF16LE (or in Windows-speak "Unicode") encoding.

Instead of using `>`, try piping the output from `jq` to a cmdlet that allows you to explicitly set the output encoding, like `Out-File`:

```
jq 'query...' $srcJson |Out-File $destinationJson -Encoding UTF8
```